Erklärung der Präpositionen, die mit Bewegung/Orten verbunden sind
Ich habe einmal hier eine Liste von den Präpositionen, die mit der Bewegung, bzw. mit Orten, zu tun haben, gesehen.  Das heißt, man geht nach Deutschland, in die USA, nach Hause, man bleibt zu Hause, man fährt in die Stadt, usw.  Könnte jemand mir erklären, ob es irgendwelche Logik hinter diesen Unterschieden steht, oder ob man sich das einfach merken muss?  Und wenn man weiß, wo diese Liste zu finden ist, wäre ich dankbar für die Information (ich weiß schon, das es etliche Liste dieser Art gibt, aber es war eine, die ziemlich komplett war, und sich nur über Bewegungen, usw handelte).

Für Namen in Richtungen ist die Grundregel, dass man in verwendet, wenn der Ort einen Artikel führt, ansonsten nach.

nach Hamburg
in die Niederlande
in den Iran
nach China


Zuhause ist ein feststehender Ausdruck, auch wenn manche ihn zu Hause schreiben. Du kannst das daran sehen, dass er einen Ort beschreibt und keine Richtung. Die Präposition zu beschreibt aber immer eine Richtung.

Danke, ja, das von "zuhause" wusste ich schon, also hätte ich es nicht erwähnen sollen.  Also haben wir "nach" ohne Artikel, und "in" mit Artikel (im allgemeinem), aber dazu kommt "ich gehe zum Arzt".  Ich weiß nicht, ob es weitere Möglichkeiten gibt...

Für Namen von Personen und Firmen wird zu verwendet, richtig. Für gewöhnliche Substantive meistens zu, seltener in oder auf.

Wann würde man „auf" benutzen, abgesehen von Personen und Firmen?  „Man geht auf den Berg", um Richtung auszudrücken?

Man geht z.B. auf die Schule oder in die Schule, je nach Dialekt.

Nicht nur Dialekt, sondern auch kontextabhängig. "Gehst Du schon zur Schule? / Gehst Du schon in die Schule?", "Gehst Du heute in die Schule?", "Auf welche Schule gehst Du?".
